# Expo (RN): Loading loca html assets with expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm want to bundle and load local html with assets with in expo managed app.

I just created blank TS project and installed `react-native-webview`. `WebView` is loading external sites well.

I added `index.html` and some assets to `assets`folder. It seems that currently Expo/RN dosn't support loading html with require (at list I didn't find how to solve it. So I push HTML code to WebView.

```
const html = `<image src="assets/splash.png" height="128" width="128"></image>`

return(
    <WebView source={{ html: html }}      
    />
)
```

But I see nothing (blank placeholder for image).  I tried different paths for instead of `assets/splash.png`, but nothing seem to work. I don't get how to make HTML load assets that are in `assets` folder? Or I should place it somewhere else?